# Update date and time in text file via Linux script or falcon : Hadoop

Tags: linux, perl, hadoop, oozie, falcon

I have some text file with below entries :

```
Name  type  startTime   Endtime    comments
my   I      01-03-2016  02-03-2016 zoom
my   F     01-03-2016  02-03-2016  zoom2
abd   F     03-03-2016  04-03-2016  zoom5
my   I      01-03-2016  02-03-2016 zoom6
```

If the Currnt date is march 18 : the output should be  :
Output :

```
Name  type  startTime   Endtime    comments
my   I      **02-03-2016**  ***18-03-2016*** zoom
my   F     01-03-2016  02-03-2016  zoom2
abd   F     03-03-2016  04-03-2016  zoom5
my   I      **02-03-2016**  ***18-03-2016*** zoom6
```

Conditions are `If name  == my && type ==I` then needs to update the start time with End time -- End time would be current date which is processed :

Can any one help me in choosing best methodology to process that file with above requirements .

I hope my requirement is cleared :) 
Thanks,
Madhu

Comment: use Text::CSV  to parse the file into hash, process it,  then write it back

Comment: can you elaborate your answer little bit . Thanks for quick response :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure Perl solution will look like

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, "<", "file.txt") || die $!;
my ($header, @lines) = <$fh>;
close($fh);

my @keys = split(/[\s\t]+/, $header);

open($fh, ">", "file.txt") || die $!;
print $fh join("\t",@keys), "\n";

my @cdate = (localtime)[3,4,5];
$cdate[1] += 1;
$cdate[2] += 1900;

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    my %tmp;
    @tmp{@keys} = split(/[\s\t]+/, $line);
    if($tmp{'Name'} eq 'my' && $tmp{'type'} eq 'I') {
        $tmp{'Endtime'} = sprintf("%02d-%02d-%04d", @cdate)
    }

    print $fh join("\t", @tmp{@keys} ),"\n"
}

close($fh)
```

Comment: Thanks Sotona .. Impressed with your answer :) .. Am very new to perl but i understood logic .. can you just help me smalle snippet in case if i don have headers ..what could be the change in code . -- Thanks a lot

Comment: if you don't have headers, you have to make sure all columns have fixed position. in this case you have to split each line into an array, then check `if ($array[0] eq 'my' && $array[1] eq 'I')` then $array[3] = _current date_

Comment: Hello sotona, The perl script is failed to run from falcon . Can you transform same in Linuxscript , Thanks in advance??

Comment: what is falcon? which version of Perl do you have there?

Comment: Falcon is a hadoop Data Governance and job scheduler . Perl version  v5.10.1 (*) . Stand alone script is working fine.. :) Thanks for the quick response . May be perl packages are not available in Falcon. So can you please transform in Linux script if Possible

Comment: well, it's possible, but the script would be way less understandable and way longer. what error do you get when trying to run this script?

Comment: The job has Killed by Oozie server .. as of bed request : Don't know actually i have checked application logs not giving any cause of the issue . .. Share me linux script .Will try to execute from falcon

Comment: can you just run the script from command line on your server and post an error? it is  possible that Bash script won't work as well

Comment: Sotona, the script  working very fine  from command line as standalone scipt. It is not at all code orperl issue. It might be with falcon packages. I guess as for now we can run only linux scipts from Falcon n oozie.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107095/discussion-between-sotona-and-mapreddy).

Comment: can you  please share the script. It is failing only by - below error       :Script failed, error message[Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]]                                         So 
1) Perlscript Buffer reader is not able to contact oozie server : So needs to look a new way : may be linux script will help us. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a shell script:

1. Read each line of file
2. Loop
3. Use cut command to read required field values
4. Do `if condition` to check values for field `name` and `type`
5. Use `sed` command to update the value for `starttime` and `endtime` fields